# Какую функцию выполняет вот эта строка

Tags: css

Какую функцию выполняет вот эта строка:

```
.extend_test.int, .int.extend_test2, .int.extend_test3
```

? Пробовал назначить `.int` на `div`, но так не работает.

---

```
.extend_test.int, .int.extend_test2, .int.extend_test3 {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: bold; }

    .extend_test, .extend_test2, .extend_test3 {
      background: #fdd; }

    .extend_test2 {
      border-radius: 10px; }

    .extend_test3 {
      border: 1px solid #808000;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px; }
```

Пытаюсь вызвать так, но не работает.

```
    <!--test-->
    <div id="first" class="extend_test">
        <div id="second" class="int">
            <p>test 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.extend_test.int` значит оба класса должны быть на одном и том же элементе (т.е. `<div id="first" class="extend_test int">`). Если вы хотите чтобы в вашем примере (который не работает) нормально было - добавьте между классами пробел: `.extend_test .int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.extend_test.int` - правило действительно для блока с класcами `extend_test` и `int`, пример:

```css
.extend_test.int {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="extend_test int">test</div>
```